# Adding required field

Tags: magento-1.9, php, module, validation, form-validation

I am using a module to process product returns, but unfortunatly the comment field is not required. I would like to add the check that people have to fill out WHY they return the product.

As far as I can find it should be in this bit of code:

```
        if ($p_qty == true) {

        $rma->save();

        //set sub products information
        foreach ($rmaProducts as $rmaProduct) {
            $id = $rmaProduct->getitem_id();

            //check
            if (isset($data['rp_qty_' . $id])) {
                $qty          = $data['rp_qty_' . $id];
                $description  = $data['rp_description_' . $id];
                $reason       = $data['rp_reason_' . $id];
                $request_type = $data['rp_request_type_' . $id];
                $rma->updateSubProductInformation($rmaProduct, $qty, $description, $reason, null, $request_type);
            }

        }

        //notify admin
        $rma->NotifyCreationToAdmin();

        //confirm & redirect
        Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess($this->__('Product Return successfully sent.'));
        $this->_redirect('ProductReturn/Front/View', array('rma_id' => $rma->getId()));
    } else {

        Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError($this->__('Please select quantities to return.'));
        $this->_redirect('ProductReturn/Front/NewRequest', array('order_id' => $data['rma_order_id']));
    }
```

Is there a easy way to edit this and make the rp_reason mandatory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you simply add the following before your code that creates the entries:

```
if (!Zend_Validate::is($data['rp_reason_'.$id], 'NotEmpty')) {
    Mage::throwException($this->__('Please provide a reason.'));
}
```

Please note that you will have to add the following try/catch block around your code:

```
try {
    // Your code here
}
catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addException($e);
    $this->_redirectReferer();
}
```

Comment: there is a closeing ] missing, but this did put me in the right direction